# Angularjs ensuring the json posted data has been transmitted

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, json, ajax

I am trying to send data from a Angularjs app to php  in order to insert it into mysql db .
I have the index.html that contains the script,getUser_api.php page and insert.php page

I hav not error  in console but I failed insert into mysql db.

So Is there any way to ensure if  json data has been transmitted or nor

```
var app =   angular.module("app",['ui.router']);    

app.controller("insertCtrl", function($scope,$rootScope, $http) {

$scope.insert = function() {

$http.post(

"getUser_api.php", {

'Customer_Name': $scope.Customer_Name,

'Cust_mail': $scope.Cust_mail,

'Cust_Address': $scope.Cust_Address

 }) ;
 }

 });
```

My insert.php page

```
<div class="well col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2" style="margin-top: 10%" ng-controller="insertCtrl"> 

<form>
    <div class="form-group">

        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="Customer_Name">

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label> mail</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="Cust_mail">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Address</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="Cust_Address">
    </div>
</form>

    <button class="btn-block btn-info" ng-click="insert()">Insert</button>
</div>
```

getUser_api

```
<?php

include('config.php');

$result=mysql_query('select * from customers');

$data['results']=array();

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
array_push($data['results'],$row);
}

if(count($data['results'])>0)
$data['status']='OK';

 else
$data['status']='Z-Result';
echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check manually, you can check it in the browser - developer tools in XHR tab.

In case if you want to catch error in the js end you can do:

```
var dataToSend = {
    'Customer_Name': $scope.Customer_Name,
    'Cust_mail': $scope.Cust_mail,
    'Cust_Address': $scope.Cust_Address
};
var req = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'getUser_api.php',
    data: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(dataToSend))
};
$http(req).then(function (response) {
    //handle success
}, function (error) {
    //handle error
});
```

How to check manually in browser:

1. Open Chrome and press F12 for developer options
2. Click on Network
3. Click on XHR
4. Now in your html page click on the button which will call your inser method.
5. Your request will be displayed like following
6. Click on the request sent
7. Click headers
8. You will be able to see your Json in Request payload

[image: example rquest header]

Comment: No error small green circle found but also no data found please more help

Comment: data has been sent successfully  how to ensure there is a reposnse from the server   {"name":"Tony","age":34,"addr":"USA"}

Comment: Click on **Preview / Respinse tab** near header. And that will give you the response. Preview tab will give you formatted output. Response will give you raw response

Comment: This found in request payroll part {"name":"Tony","age":34,"addr":"USA"}  what is that means?

Comment: In preview and response pages only index.html page and the .php on the server side only

Comment: Please add screenshot of Network tab  with Preview tab open - for better understanding

Comment: The issue is happening in php. Instead of returning json it is returning the page. Nothing wrong in angularjs code

Comment: I changed my php page and it works perfect. thank you